# Creating a function to print an answer w/ Jprompt

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a word matching game. In this game the program generates a set of words, "keys" and a set of "descriptions". The goal of this program is create a set of "keys" that can be matched to a set of "descriptions". For example, element with id `el1` should be paired with element with id `dl1`.

I've created the html for the user interface and the javascript for rendering the html. There is a button that shows the answer for the game. When the button is clicked `show_answer()` is called.

```
    // initialize the answer.
    var answer = '';
```

```
   function show_answer() {
      // retrieve the keys and descriptions. Then load them into their respective arrays.
      const e_inputs = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='el']");
      const d_inputs = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='dl']");
      let elArray = [];
      let dlArray = [];
      const title = document.getElementById('title_input').value;
      for (let i = numberOfInputs; i < elArray.length; i++) {
          text += `${elArray[i]}:${dlArray[i]}\n`;
          answer += elArray[i];
          answer += ':';
          answer += dlArray[i];
          answer += '\n';
      }
      jAlert(answer, 'Correct Match');
    }
```

The issue is that the answer is coming back blank.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a runnable [mcve] to demonstrate?  When you step through the code in your browser's debugging tools, what value does `answer` have when invoking the `jAlert`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function show_answer() {
      // retrieve the keys and descriptions. Then load them into their respective arrays.
      const e_inputs = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='el']");
      const d_inputs = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='dl']");
      let elArray = [];
      let dlArray = [];
      const title = document.getElementById('title_input').value;
      e_inputs.forEach( i => { if(i.value) elArray.push(i.value) });
      d_inputs.forEach( i => { if(i.value) dlArray.push(i.value) });

      //reset the answer once the generate_html() is called.
      answer = '';
      for (let i = 0; i < elArray.length; i++) {
          answer += `${elArray[i]}`;
          answer += ':';
          answer += `${dlArray[i]}`;
          answer += '\n';
      }
      jAlert(answer, 'Correct Match');
    }
```